# This code replaces each element of an array with the product of every element of the array except the current one. Suggestions for improvement?

Tags: typescript

This code replaces each element in an array with the product of
every other element in the array but the current element, without using division. So, for the array [5,2,3], the program outputs [6,18,108].

The code is below, but in essence, it iterates through each element, and sets the element to the product of the other elements.

So, for the array [5,2,3], it replaces the first element with the product of 2*3, so the array becomes [6,2,3]. Then it replaces the second element with the product of 6 and 3, so the array becomes [6,18,3]. Finally, it replaces the third element with the product of 6 and 18, so the array becomes [6,18,108].

Looking for general suggestions here, like how to improve the time complexity ([someone suggested using some sort of different type of product or something](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/267846/replace-array-values-with-product-of-all-other-values) but I don't know how to do that)

```
// productOfArray
// This function calculates the product of every value in the given array.
function productOfArray(array: number[])
{
    let product = 1;
    for (let x of array)
        product *= x; // should I be using *= or write product = product * x?
    return product;
}

// replaceWithProduct
// This function replaces each element in an array with the product of
// every other element in the array but the current element.
function replaceWithProduct(array: number[])
{
    for (let i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        let arrayWithoutElement = array.slice(0,i).concat(array.slice(i+1,array.length));
        array[i] = productOfArray(arrayWithoutElement);
    }
    return array;
}

// Test the above functions.
let array = [5,2,3];
console.assert(productOfArray(array) === 30);
let newArray = replaceWithProduct(array);
let testArray = [6,18,108]; // This is what newArray should be.
for (let i=0; i<testArray.length; i++)
    console.assert(newArray[i] === testArray[i]);

console.log("Finished");
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that the result you are aiming for is the result that the "question" is aiming for. I'd expect `[5, 2, 3]` to be `[6, 15, 10]` by the description ...

Answer (score 3):

The `productOfArray` could be implemented by [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
function productOfArray(array: number[]): number {
  return array.reduce((product, e) => product *= e, 1)
}
```

The `reduce` method could also be used to implement the `replaceWithProduct` function, if you reorganize the algorithm a bit.

```
function replaceWithProduct(source: number[]): number[] {
  return source.reduce(reducer, []);
}

function reducer(acc: number[], e: number, i: number, source: number[]): number[] {
  return acc.concat(productOfArray(acc) * productOfArray(source.slice(i + 1)));
}
```

It calculates a sprecific element by mulitplying the product of the already considered elements with all *rest* elements. This approach is only simpler, if you are familar with `reduce`, I guess.

To minimize the computations, you could cache and update the products instead of recalculating them in every `reducer` call.

```
function replaceWithProduct(source: number[]): number[] {
  return source.reduce(withReducer(source), []);
}

function withReducer(source: number[]): (acc: number[], e: number) => number[] {
  let lastAccProduct = 1;
  let lastRestProduct = productOfArray(source);

  return (acc: number[], e: number): number[] => {
    lastRestProduct /= e;
    const currentProduct = lastAccProduct * lastRestProduct;
    lastAccProduct *= currentProduct;
    return acc.concat(currentProduct);
  };
}
```

The example encapsulates the cache values within a [High Order Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), which means, that `withReducer` is a function, which returns another function. If the concept is new to you, it's possibly hard to understand.

---

With the restriction of avoiding division, you need to compute the *rest products* by processing the array from right to left. Therefore you can use `reduceRight`. The complexity keeps the same as with last example.

```
function replaceWithProduct(source: number[]): number[] {
  return source.reduce(withReducer(source), []);
}

function withReducer(source: number[]): (acc: number[], e: number) => number[] {
  const restProducts = calculateRestProducts(source);
  let accProduct = 1;

  return (acc: number[], e: number): number[] => {
    const currentProduct = accProduct * restProducts.shift();
    accProduct *= currentProduct;
    return acc.concat(currentProduct);
  };
}

function calculateRestProducts(source: number[]): number[] {
  let lastRestProduct = 1;
  return source
    .slice(1)
    .reduceRight((acc, e) => acc.concat(lastRestProduct *= e), [1])
    .reverse();
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't I need to recalculate the product?

Comment: The code presented here is not well-behaved when the input array contains a 0

Comment: That, and your code feels hacky.

Comment: I guess, if you are familar with functional programming concepts, it's straighforward. The introduction of the cache variables reduces the complexity from n^2 to n, because the full recalculation of the product would consinder (n-1) elements, which isn't necessary with the cache variables `lastAccProduct`, `lastRestProduct`. Since there was nothing said about the zero handling, I didn't cover it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually need to replace the result into the original array? That makes it unnecessarily complicated in my opinion (and is bad practice). Why not just return a new array?

The logic can also be simplified by just calculating the product of all numbers and then dividing that with each number in turn:

```
function productsOfOthers(numbers) {
  const product = numbers.reduce((product, e) => product * e, 1);
  return numbers.map(n => product / n);
}
```

And if you really need it to be the same array at the end, wrap it in a function that copies the result back:

```
function copyIntoArray(source, target) {
   source.forEach((n, i) => target[i] = n);

   // Could be left out, if you know/assume they are the same length,
   // as it is in this case
   if (target.length > source.length) {
      target.length = source.length;
   }
}

function replaceWithProduct(numbers) {
  const products = productsOfOthers(numbers);
  copyIntoArray(products, numbers);

  // Could just as well not return anything since you are reusing the array anyway
  return numbers;
}
```

This is the \$O(2n)\$ (or \$O(3n)\$ in case of the copying) = \$O(n)\$ instead of (i believe) \$O(n^2)\$ due to the repeated multiplication.

One draw back maybe a slight risk of overflow, however if the product of all numbers overflow, it's very likely that the product of all except one would overflow too anyway. Or use BigInt.

---

## If zeros are allowed...

This makes it a bit more complicated, however one could write a product method, that counts the zeros and ignores them for the product:

```
function product(numbers) {
   return numbers.reduce(
     ({product, zeros}, n) => 
       n === 0 ? 
         {product, zeros: zeros + 1} :
         {product: product * n, zeros}, 
     {product: 1,  zeros: 0}
   );
}
```

And then build the result based on the number of zeros counted:

```
function productsOfOthers(numbers) {
  const {product, zeros} = product(numbers);
  switch (zeros) {
    case 0: 
      return numbers.map(n => product / n);
    case 1:
      return numbers.map(n => n === 0 ? product : 0)
    default:
      return Array(numbers.length).fill(0);
  }
}
```

---

## When division isn't allowed

In this case I'd avoid all the expensive slicing and concatenating and write a product function that ignores a specific index:

```
function product(numbers, ignoreIndex) {
  return numbers.reduce(
    (product, n, index) => 
      index === ignoreIndex ? product : product * n, 
    1
  );
}

function productsOfOthers(numbers) {
  return numbers.map((_, index, array) => product(array, index));
}
```

---

And since I seem to be on a roll, here is a version that reuses the product of the first numbers. I moved away from functional programming, because I believe it would become too difficult to read in this case.

```
function productFromIndex(numbers, index) {
  let product = 1;
  for (let i = index; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    product *= numbers[i];
  }
  return product;
}

function productsOfOthers(numbers) {
  let previousProduct = 1;
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    result[i] = previousProduct * productFromIndex(numbers, i + 1);
    previousProduct *= numbers[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention: The original challenge does not allow division.

Comment: This algorithm utterly fails if the array contains zeros. Even if you attempt to avoid dividing by zero, having two (or more) zeros in the array should give a result of all zeros.

Comment: @Vogel612 I've added some alternatives.

Comment: @moonman239 I've added some alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

> There are two ways of constructing a software design: One way is to
> make it so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies, and the
> other way is to make it so complicated that there are no obvious
> deficiencies.
>
> — C. A. R. Hoare

```
const productWithout = (arr: number[], idx: number) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, v, idx2) => (idx === idx2 ? acc : v * acc), 1);

const replaceIn = (arr: number[], idx: number, v: number) =>
  arr.map((r, idx2) => (idx === idx2 ? v : r));

const replaceWithProduct = (arr: number[]) =>
  arr.reduce(
    (acc, _, idx) => replaceIn(acc, idx, productWithout(acc, idx)),
    arr
  );
```